# How to return a list of directories that include a specific subdirectory?

Tags: ssh

I am wanting to retrieve a list of directories that include a subdirectory named "/admin/news"

I have tried `find '/admin/news' -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'` within the directory but it just say `find: ‘/admin/news’: No such file or directory`.

Comment: The directories in your search are counted in the depth. So try ```-maxdepth 3```.

Comment: @nikost tried that and it still returns with `find: ‘/admin/news’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try including the directory to find in, if its the current directory then use ```.```. Something like ```find . '/admin/news' -maxdepth 3 -type d -printf '%f\n'

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the directories in your search pattern count toward your search `maxdepth`. So be sure to adjust accordingly.

If the admin folder is in your root directory, then you should specify the starting search path as `/`.

```
find / '/admin/news/' -type d -maxdepth 3 -printf '%f\n'
```

If admin is a subdirectory from your current working directory then use `.` to specify the search should start from the current working direcotry.

```
find . '/admin/news/' -type d -maxdepth 3 -printf '%f\n'
```